# JavaScript having hard time using local variables

Tags: javascript, variables, local

I wish to make some variables local instead of global, but I am having problems getting them local, it seems to just ruin the whole code for me when I attempt that. If anyone is able to help me out, it would be greatly appreciated, thanks. The variables I want to be local are "cardOne", "cardTwo" and cardSum, this is an assignment I gotta do, and they only want the array as global. (I am also a beginner so my code may look messy)

Here is my code if you can help out:

```
//adding the cards together, with parameter passing
function cardNumber(one, two) {
    var cardTotal = one + two;
    alert(`Your card numbers are ${one} and ${two}!`);
    return cardTotal;
}

var cardRange = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var cardOne = cardRange[Math.floor(Math.random() * cardRange.length)];
var cardTwo = cardRange[Math.floor(Math.random() * cardRange.length)];
//calling the cardNumber function (parameter passing shown)
var cardSum = cardNumber(cardOne, cardTwo);

//adding the cards together if the user wants an extra card, with parameter passing
function moreCards(nextCard, total) {
    alert(`Your extra card is ${nextCard}!`);
    var cardTotal = nextCard + total;
    return cardTotal;
}

//this function gets the user's input and also may call the moreCards function, depending on the user's choice.
function inputValidation() {
    var counter;
    for (counter = 0; counter < 3;) {
        //Asks the user if they want another card, they can do this up to three times, depending on their choice and card sum.
        var input = prompt(`Which makes your card total ${cardSum}. Would you like to draw another card? (Type in 1 for yes, 0 for no, or select cancel to return to home.)`);
        if (input === null) {
            //takes you back to pontoonhome.html
            window.location.replace("pontoonhome.html").src = "homepage";
            counter += 3;
        }
        //Random number doesn't change
        else if (input === "1") {
            counter++;
            var extraCard = cardRange[Math.floor(Math.random() * cardRange.length)];
            //calling the moreCards function
            cardSum = moreCards(extraCard, cardSum);
        }
        else if (input === "0") {
            //If the user declines to another card
            counter += 3;
        }
        else {
            //If the user puts in an invalid input
            alert("Wrong input, enter 1 or 0 on your keyboard!");
        }
        if (cardSum >= 22) {
            //If the user gets above 22 (bust)
            counter += 3;
        }
    }
}

//this function is called if you lose
function youLose() {
    if (cardSum >= 22) {
        alert("BUST!");
        document.write(`You got ${cardSum}, which is above 21, that means you got a bust! Therefore, you lose!`);
    }
    if(cardSum <18) {
        document.write(`You got ${cardSum}, and the AI player got 18. You got a value lower than the computer's score, meaning you lose!`);
    }
    document.getElementById("loss").src = "images/dislike-157252_640.png";
    var audio = document.getElementById("loser");
    audio.src = "audio/loser.wav";
    audio.play();
}

//this function is called if you win
function youWin() {
    document.write(`You got ${cardSum}, and the AI player got 18, which means you win! <br>`);
    document.getElementById("victory").src = "images/hand-157251_640.png";
    var audio = document.getElementById("winner");
    audio.src = "audio/winner.wav";
    audio.play();
}

//this function is called if you are tied with the AI player
function draw(){
    document.write(`You got ${cardSum}, and the AI player got 18. Which means it is a tie!`);
    document.getElementById("draw").src = "images/draw.png";
    var audio = document.getElementById("tie");
    audio.src = "audio/draw.wav";
    audio.play();
}
//This function decides the fate of the game.
function pontoonDecision() {

    if (cardSum >= 22) {
        youLose();
    }
    else if (cardSum > 18 && cardSum < 22) {
        youWin();

    }
    else if (cardSum === 18) {
        draw();
    }
    else {
        youLose();
    }
    //else is if the card sum is below 18.
}

//calling the input and decision functions
inputValidation();
pontoonDecision();
```

Comment: :v you could wrap it in an IIFE, *technically* it would be local. The syntax is `(function() {...})()` and you just replace the ellipsis with your code.

Comment: when I do that, it ruins it, because it cannot find cardSum...

Comment: no i mean wrap EVERYTHING in it :)

Comment: I don't think they would allow that, even though it sounds smart.

Comment: ouch, I'll find another way then

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) to achieve what you describe.

By the way, `var` makes variables scope global while `let` keeps it local.

Comment: OOP tries to abstract your program by making everything objects, and actions in your program are represented by one object mutating the other i think idk im not a oop person

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects

Comment: I do not get how I put this into my existing code though